# How to have optional split screen layout in HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a panel full of tiles that can be any length, including scrolling beyond the lower bounds of the viewport, so the vertical scroll is currently in use for this.

What I want to have, is an optional lower panel than can be shown or hidden at the users request, which will always take up the lower 25% of the screen. The tiles above should then shrink to a scrolling pane ABOVE this, so you can independently scroll the tiles, without changing the position of the lower panel.

So I need an outer container that is always 100% of the screen height, with no scrolling.

Within that, I want a panel of scrollable content. If this is the only panel visible, then it should take up 100% height of the outer container, giving the illusion that the main screen is scrolling.

When the lower panel is visible, the scrollable content should only take up the first 75% of the screen height and the scroll bar is only 75% of the height to reflect this. The lower 25% is the new panel which should be fixed. The lower panel should ALSO be independently scrollable. So you end up with two independently scrolling panels stacked on top of each other

I've tried to do this with flexbox but am not having any luck. Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong?

Fiddle below

[https://jsfiddle.net/cdg6815s/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/cdg6815s/1/)

```
.app-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0.8;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.logtailContainer {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0.2;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Just add `body, html {height: 100%; margin: 0;}` and probably `* {box-sizing: border-box;}` - check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/m1rxL45v/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** skobaljic's comment is a way simpler way to do this. I'm keeping this answer as it still works.

I'm assuming you want something like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contentpanel {
  max-height: 75vh;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 75vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.lowerpanel {
  max-height: 25vh;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 25vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<body class="b">

  <div class="app-container">
    <div class="contentpanel">
      App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App
      tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="lowerpanel">
      Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br
      /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

A few issues:

1. You are setting the `.app-container` to 100% height, but of what. You need to set a reference, so setting the height on the body/html is necessary.
2. `flex` property is shorthand - so you were setting the flex grow (as you may know), but that's the ratio to what it will grow. Setting the flex-basis property to the height might be the better way to go.
3. I changed the height values to `vh` units to use the viewport height as reference.
4. Setting `max-height` on your elements instead of height, allows for them to shrink/grow but stop at the specific height value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just one last thing - the lower panel needs to be hidden or displayed on user preference. I was going to use display none/block - but currently with that CSS if the lower panel is hidden, the top panel only fills 75% of the height. I assume to get it to fill the whole screen if the lower panel isn't there, I change both 75vh to 100vh?

Comment: How are you toggling it? JS?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `flex`, you can use `flex:1;`or `flex-grow:1` on the main container instead setting a fixed `height` and only set an `height`/`min-height` on the second container that can be hidden.
to fill the window, height:100vh and a margin reset for body is also efficient here.
if `border` and `padding` are involved, mind also the `box-sizing` model to include them in your sizing.

here is a demo with a checkbox to toggle hide/show for the second container and `box-sizing` to mind the `padding` of `.app-container` to calculate the 100vh height.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contentpanel {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.lowerpanel {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 4em;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* demo purpose CSS to use input/label to toggle display of lowerpanel */
#hide {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100vw;
}

[for="hide"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #bee;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

#hide:checked~.lowerpanel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-container">

  <input type="checkbox" id="hide"><!-- input for demo purpose -->
  
  <div class="contentpanel">

    <label for="hide">toggle red container</label><!-- label for demo purpose -->

    App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles
    <br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br /> App tiles<br /><br />
  </div>
  <div class="lowerpanel">
    Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br
    /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br /> Logtail stuff<br /><br />
  </div>
  </div
```